# How can combusted methane from landfill samples be quantified?

Tags: microbiology, theoretical-biology, environment, thermodynamics

**Background:**

For my studies I'm wanting and attempting to make a landfill greenhouse gas emissions (GHG) model that predicts the amount of greenhouse gas equivalent emissions ($GHG_{eq}$ [tonnes/year]) by analysing a series of landfill core drill samples and extrapolating the data to predict how much GHGs would be produced if the samples can be representative of the landfill as a whole and allowed to naturally degrade. Note that this comes with the assumption of minimal heterogeneity which I know is not the best assumption for most landfills but I'm hoping to get a LOT of data (it's better than nothing).

As the most notorious GHG from landfill is methane, I'm going to simplify this question to just predicting the amount of methane which would be produced from the (combustible) material in landfill assuming it would just sit there forever.

Note that I have cross-posted my question [from the chemistry stack exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/168959/how-can-combusted-methane-from-landfill-samples-be-quantified).

**The Data:**

I have this data which is the average of 3 landfill drill core samples and shows the type of waste which has been calculated from sorting and weighing different types of material found in landfill (Table 1) and the chemical composition and high heating value (HHV)/calorific value of the material (Table 2) which I've had tested in an independent lab. For Table 1, an assumed "type" of plastic, rubber, wood (etc.) is made with a constant chemical composition to simplify the model (although I do recognise that there are many different types of plastics and woods etc.).

[image: Data for average of 3 landfill drill core samples]

**The Method (?):**

I've seen the generic methanogenesis combustion reaction as:

$$CO_2 + 4H_2 \longrightarrow CH_4 + 2H_2O$$

I've also seen an elemental formula for hydrocarbon combustions along the lines of:

$$C_xH_y + (x + \frac{y}{4})O_2 \longrightarrow xCO_2 = \frac{y}{2}H_2O + Heat + Light$$

I know how to calculate the conversion rate going from any GHG such as $CO_2$ or $CH_4$ to $GHG_{eq}$ but it's this first step - the predicting of the GHGs themselves with what formula - which I'm lost at.

**The Questions:**

1. How can I calculate $CH_4$ from landfill samples with the attached data and which reaction should be used?
2. (Bonus) What other considerations should be accounted for with any of the other data? (e.g. the Sulfur going into $SO_2$ emissions (etc.)).

Comment: If this doesn't work on biology, try [sustainability.se] or [earthscience.se], though it's unclear to me where this question fits best. Please take the tour, read the help centre before posting etc..

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. Is your aim simply to utilize existing models to predict methane production from this landfill, or to test different models with empirical experimentation? After a quick web search, I found several reports on methane production from landfills or municipal solid waste. Several of them cited the IPCC First Order Decay (FOD) method, which should be accessible online. Also saw at least one cite the LandGEM model, accessible on the US EPA [website](https://www.epa.gov/air-emissions-factors-and-quantification/emissions-estimation-tools).

Comment: Hmmm, I suspect this will be much much harder than you think. You would need to know the decomposition rates of each of the different carbon sources, and the biological utilization under the different conditions. You might be able to get some sorts of models for some plant-based waste from industrial composting studies. You should also note that paper ~= wood, as it's almost entirely made from cellulose derived from wood, and how do these differ from "organic"? To a chemist organic means carbon-based - including plastics! It has no special meaning in biology other than in farming/production.

Comment: @MikeyC I saw the LandGEM model and some other (licenced) ones online but I'm really looking to make a model from the ground up to be honest, that way I can fully understand what's going on. If it indeed becomes too challenging then I'll try and look for another model.

Comment: @bob1 Yes I'll need to make some assumptions certainly, great points. But rather than focusing on the scope of the whole landfill site as it's certainly too broad, what about the specific landfill drill core samples themselves on a case-by-case basis? Then I can process multiple samples and plot the heterogeneity.

Comment: Why would you reinvent the wheel? Real people doing real work with landfills in the real world are using existing models. It seems your first step should be not to build from the ground up but to understand the existing models, and only propose changes if you can find an improvement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross-posted across the network [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/168959/how-can-combusted-methane-from-landfill-samples-be-quantified) ansd [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24482/how-can-combusted-methane-from-landfill-samples-be-quantified) with an [upvoted answer at Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/168992/48443).

Comment: Good point Bryan. @AliceD I have not declared any answer as correct yet, this question is not solved. I also upvoted the answer here? Im still processing answers. There have been brilliant other insights I've had from posting on other stack exchanges which you are limiting by closing this thread for unsubstantial reasoning. You are preventing dialogue and thus critical thinking capability.

Comment: Cross-posting across the SE network is discouraged network wide. FWIW: I flagged the other cross-post as well for mod attention. In the future, please post a question only on the most suitable site. The community will then decide whether it's appropriate. If not, it can be migrated.

Comment: Why then did the mods from chemistry stack exchange request me to post to other stack exchange websites? Logic doesn't add up.

Answer (score 1):

Methane production in landfills is a biological process that is carried out in 4 steps: hydrolysis, acidogenesis, acetogenesis and methanogenesis. In the first step, organic matter (for the sake of the this argument, let's consider carbohydrates, fat and proteins) is hydrolysed into less complex compounds (monosaccharides, fatty acids and aminoacids). In the second step, these compounds are fermented into fermentation products (FP) such as acetate, propionate, butyrate among many others; in the third step, the FP are converted by acetogens into acetate, which is converted into methane by methanogenic bacteria in the last step.

Each of the 4 steps mentioned are carried out by different bacteria and they also release other gases such as H2 and CO2 that can be used to produce methane, or are simply released to the atmosphere. Because protein contains nitrogen and sulphur, other gases can be produced (e.g. NH3, NO2, NO3, H2S, SO2, etc..). The process as while increases in complexity when others less prevalent organic compounds are considered, or simply by taking into account other materials that you mention in Table 1.

To answer your questions, I don't think you have enough information to build your model. Considering that more than 50% of your waste is organic, I would find a way to fractionate it into the 3 major components. From there, in the literature, you can find plenty of data regarding the conversion of waste into methane and what you could expect in a landfill with similar composition. Of course, ideally, you would even get actual data from similar landfills to feed your model. A similar process could be done to the other materials that are dumped into the landfills you are studying. The more you fractionate and the more you can estimate how much methane comes from each fraction, the less error your model with have in the end.

As for the sulphur, as far as I know, most of it will come from the metabolism of protein, so if you can measure the amount of protein that is dumped to the landfills, then you will be able to know how much SO2 is expected to be generated (again, there should be literature available regarding how much it is expected).

Good luck with you project.